# how can I choose my integration approach

Tags: web-services, integration, soa, mediator

I want to build an environment using data from a set of data stored in databases in 3 platform (plat1, plat2, plat3). I have to choose a integration approach or architecture , after a search I found that the virtual integration is better than integration materialized "data stored in a central database data warhouse or federated database", because I want my Data will be fresh, I have a autonomous sources, I want my integration system will be more flexible if I want to add other sources.

virtual integration that I have chosen is based on a mediator and wrappers, I found problems in the implementation of this architecture, normally my mediator and wrappers are web services that must be provided by a soap eg I need be based on a soa archiecture ? or we must mixed the two model "virtual and soa", Please clear me this confusion and there is a integration platform open source i can use it , I saw WSO2, and I don't know if suitable or not? I hope that my question is clear to you, and I wait  any answer will be useful for me
 thank you in advance